# How to show item in revit file using Forge Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge, autodesk-bim360

We have a web app connected with Autodesk Forge. We were able to upload and view revit files and get the metadata of the file. Now, we want to view specific item in the file without viewing the whole file. How can we make that using the Forge Viewer??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

The correct option to pass in should be `ids` and not `dbids`, been a while since I used this so had to brush up on it...

Yes simply pass in an array of dbids for Viewer to partially load the model:

```
const options = {
ids: [233,2333 ...]
//...
}

viewer.start/loadModel(svfUrl, options) // or viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, geom, options)
```

Note that with this approach there's no option to load the rest of the nodes back w/o reloading the entire model with their dbids passed in again.

Also note that dbids are inconsistent between conversions (they are subject to change if the model is translated again) so use externalIds of a node to map it to a component in the editor space (Revit).

Comment: how can i get the dbids of objects??

Comment: Try these two endpoints [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-GET/) and [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/) - the objectids are equivalent to dbids/nodeids ...

Comment: i tried viewer.start(svfUrl, options) but it still showing the whole model not the item.

Comment: See a live demo [here](https://jsbin.com/wuquhus/edit?js,output). Sorry see edit ...